# Is the risk of explosion increased by calling and charging a cell phone at the same time?

Tags: safety, mobile-phones, electronics

I have often heard that charging a cell phone and calling in the same time may cause the cell phone to explode.

Here is a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=589238621163598&set=a.191858267568304.47981.100002323972762&type=1&theater) that has pictures of what is claimed to be one such example.  [Caution: pictures may be distressing and may not be safe-for-work.]

The French text that goes with the picture pretty much tells the story of a child answering his phone while it was charging. The text describes some unexpected symptoms that are a bit unexpected: he suffered a heart attack, his face changed color and he received a burnt hand .

If you just Google "cell phone charging danger", you will get many hits telling the same kind of story.

Can mobile phone explode if you use the phone and charge simultaneously?

Comment: Is there an actual notable claim here? There's nothing telling me that the photo has any link to "charging". I'll give you it *could* be pictures of the aftermath of a mobile phone explosion. I think [this is the notable claim that this question is after](http://urbanlegends.about.com/library/bl_cell_phone_electrocuted.htm)

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for your comment. I added some information to prove how common is this claim.

Comment: THe first hit of your [google query](https://www.google.at/#q=cell+phone+charging+danger) returns this [article](http://wafflesatnoon.com/cell-phone-charging-dangers/) . Maybe it answers your question.